# Tasseled Cap Transformation LANDSAT Collection 2

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, imagery, satellite

Are there any specific coefficients available for applying the Tasseled Cap Transformation to LANDSAT 5-8 Collection 2 data?

Answer (score 3):

The coefficients are sensor specific and can be found through Google Scholar.

For Landsat 8 & 9, you can use the following coefficients:

[image: Landsat-8 Tassled Cap Coefficients]

Here are the coefficients for Sentinel-2:

[image]

### Sources

Baig, M. H. A., Zhang, L., Shuai, T., & Tong, Q. (2014). Derivation of a tasselled cap transformation based on Landsat 8 at-satellite reflectance. Remote Sensing Letters, 5(5), 423-431.

Shi, T., & Xu, H. (2019). Derivation of tasseled cap transformation coefficients for Sentinel-2 MSI at-sensor reflectance data. IEEE Journal of Selected Topics in Applied Earth Observations and Remote Sensing, 12(10), 4038-4048.